# Refinitive Eikon login message

Tags: c#, refinitiv-eikon

I am getting the following message when I try to log on to Eikon.  Does anyone have any ideas?  It used to work fine.  I have tried a different email and password and it tells me immediately that they are wrong, so it can't be my login details.  I have uninstalled Eikon and Installed it again.  Same problem,

---

**REFINITIV EIKON**

**Desktop 4.0.54 (build 4.0.54058)**

> Error description: Configuration Download Error The application failed
> to download the product configuration.
>
> Possible causes:
>
> ```
>     • you are not connected to the network 
>     • the Refinitiv Platform is encountering problems 
>     • the desktop configuration is incorrect
> ```
>
> Please restore the network connection or contact your system administrator.

**Technical Information:
'CBootstrapImpl::LoadProviders'**

Comment: You might want to contact Eikon technical support https://my.refinitiv.com/content/mytr/en/helpandsupport.html

Comment: This question is tagged with `c#`.  Are you writing any code or trying to access the API?

Comment: See https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/48110/configuration-download-error-in-eikon.html